# Docker node flow-bin libelf.so.1 not found (gitlab ci)

Tags: node.js, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

While running FlowJS check
`node_modules/.bin/flow check` inside docker image based on `node:latest` (currently 6.5)

You see error

```
$ npm i

...

npm info lifecycle flow-bin@0.31.1~postinstall: flow-bin@0.31.1

> flow-bin@0.31.1 postinstall .../node_modules/flow-bin
> node lib/install.js

✖ The `.../node_modules/flow-bin/vendor/flow` binary doesn't seem to work correctly
✖ flow binary test failed

...

$ node_modules/.bin/flow check
.../node_modules/flow-bin/vendor/flow: error while loading shared libraries: libelf.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ERROR: Build failed: exit code 1
```

E.g. `flow` cannot be run under vanilla `node:latest` docker image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related issue https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/210

In case your image is from `node:latest` (which is `debian:jessie` under the hood)
you need to add a little bit update to `apt`:

```
$ apt-get update -qq
$ apt-get install -qy libelf1
```

*before* any runs (e.g. in `Dockerfile` or corresponding section of `.gitlab-ci.yml`)

Comment: If you have this issue, please take a time to up-vote the relevant `flow-bin` issue. https://github.com/flowtype/flow-bin/issues/58